# elif iterating more than expected

Tags: python

I'm making an text based game but even if the player inputs a valid direction both 'true' and 'false' statements print, how can I stop this?

```
# A dictionary for the simplified dragon text game
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }

exit_game = False
current_area = 'Great Hall'
movement = ['North', 'East', 'South', 'West', 'Exit']
direction = ''  # player direction will be defined by player input
print('Movement: North, East, South, West, or Exit.')
print('-' * 50)
while direction != 'exit' and direction != 'Exit':
    # prints available direction
    # print(*rooms[current_area].keys())
    # prints available room
    # print(*rooms[current_area].values())
    # prints both
    # print('To your ', *rooms[current_area].keys(),' is the ', *rooms[current_area].values(), '.', sep='')
    # ---------------------------------------------
    print('Your are in the: ', current_area, '.', sep='')
    print('To your ', *rooms[current_area].keys(), ' is the ', *rooms[current_area].values(), '.', sep='')
    direction = input('Which way do you want to move?')
    print('You entered:', direction)
    direction = direction.capitalize()
    for value in rooms.values():
        if direction in value:
            print('True')
        elif direction not in value:
            print('false')
            break
    print('-' * 50)
```

I tried capitalizing the users input before the for loop but i'm stuck...

Comment: `for value in rooms.values()` You're comparing the user input to **every** possible exit direction in **every** room.  Why?  Surely you want to to compare the user input to the exit directions for **only the current room**.

Comment: `elif` doesn't iterate _at all_, ever: Iterating isn't its job. `while` or `for` do that -- but if you think `direction in value` isn't behaving the way you expect, you should be logging `repr(direction)` and `repr(value)`.

Comment: Also, in general, if your `elif` is an exact inverse of the `if` clause, then you should just use an `else` and not an `elif` at all.

Comment: Yeah I realized the issues that would occur after the fact... @John_Gordon

Comment: I guess it wouldn't harm anything but I put it there primarily for readability, though it should be easy enough to read. @Charles_Duffy

Comment: FYI I went ahead and updated my while loop using exit_game.capitalize() for anyone that notices the error

while direction != exit_game and direction != exit_game:
exit_game = 'exit'.capitalize()

Answer (score 3):

You wrote this:

```
    for value in rooms.values():
        if direction in value:
            print('True')
        elif direction not in value:
            print('false')
            break
```

Rather than a `for` loop, you apparently
just wanted to test `if direction in rooms[current_area].values():`.

Just before that add

```
print("keys:",   rooms[current_area].keys())
print("values:", rooms[current_area].values())
```

to verify that it contains the list that you *think* it contains.

---

You noticed both "true" and "false" in the output.
That's because some loop iterations would print one,
and some the other.
If during the "print() debugging" stage you had used e.g. `print(value, 'false')`,
you would have seen that false is printed for just a subset of the values.

Comment: if direction in rooms[current_area].keys():
        print('True')
    elif direction not in rooms[current_area].keys():
        print('false')

Ohh I get what you mean now. I wasnt referencing [current_area], so even if it was 'true' it wouldn't have been a valid direction according to the players current_area. Thank you very much.